# xslt for-each repeating same for all the nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes, repeat

**Source XML:**
Same node is repeated in the for-each used in the xslt. I need to loop it through all the line items. If i have 3 line items, for-each is repeated 3 times with the same first line item..

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <orders xmlns="http://www.oracle.com">
                    <product-lineitems>
                    <product-lineitem>
                        <net-price>100.00</net-price>
                        <tax>6.35</tax>
                        <gross-price>106.35</gross-price>
                        <base-price>100</base-price>
                        <lineitem-text>Originals Modern</lineitem-text>
                        <tax-basis>100.00</tax-basis>
                        <product-id>TW2P84400ZA</product-id>
                        <product-name>The Waterbury</product-name>
                        <quantity unit="">1.0</quantity>
                        <tax-rate>0.0635</tax-rate>
                        <shipment-id>1234</shipment-id>
                    </product-lineitem>
                    <product-lineitem>
                        <net-price>130.00</net-price>
                        <tax>8.26</tax>
                        <gross-price>138.26</gross-price>
                        <base-price>65.00</base-price>
                        <lineitem-text>Weekender Slip-thru</lineitem-text>
                        <tax-basis>130.00</tax-basis>
                        <product-id>TW2P919009J</product-id>
                        <product-name>Weekender Fairfield65</product-name>
                        <quantity unit="">2.0</quantity>
                        <tax-rate>0.0635</tax-rate>
                        <shipment-id>1234</shipment-id>
                        <price-adjustments>
                            <price-adjustment>
                                <net-price>-26.00</net-price>
                                <tax>-1.65</tax>
                                <gross-price>-27.65</gross-price>
                                <base-price>-26.00</base-price>
                                <tax-basis>-26.00</tax-basis>
                                <promotion-id>fathers_day_20</promotion-id>
                                <campaign-id>FATHER'S DAY 20% OFF - 04/01/14 9:22:15 am</campaign-id>
                                <coupon-id>FATHER20</coupon-id>
                            </price-adjustment>
                        </price-adjustments>
                    </product-lineitem>
                    <product-lineitem>
                        <net-price>60.00</net-price>
                        <tax>3.81</tax>
                        <gross-price>63.81</gross-price>
                        <base-price>20.00</base-price>
                        <lineitem-text>Straps - Weekender</lineitem-text>
                        <tax-basis>60.00</tax-basis>
                        <product-id>TW7C06900GZ</product-id>
                        <product-name>Weekender™ Fairfield Red/White/Blue Strap, 20mm</product-name>
                        <quantity unit="">3.0</quantity>
                        <tax-rate>0.0635</tax-rate>
                        <shipment-id>1234</shipment-id>
                        <price-adjustments>
                            <price-adjustment>
                                <net-price>-12.00</net-price>
                                <tax>-0.76</tax>
                                <gross-price>-12.76</gross-price>
                                <base-price>-12.00</base-price>
                                <tax-basis>-12.00</tax-basis>
                                <promotion-id>fathers_day_20</promotion-id>
                                <campaign-id>FATHER'S DAY 20% OFF - 04/01/14 9:22:15 am</campaign-id>
                                <coupon-id>FATHER20</coupon-id>
                            </price-adjustment>
                        </price-adjustments>
                    </product-lineitem>
                </product-lineitems>
                <shipping-lineitems>
                    <shipping-lineitem>
                        <net-price>12.95</net-price>
                        <tax>0.82</tax>
                        <gross-price>13.77</gross-price>
                        <base-price>12.95</base-price>
                        <lineitem-text>Shipping</lineitem-text>
                        <tax-basis>12.95</tax-basis>
                        <price-adjustment>
                            <net-price>-7.95</net-price>
                            <tax>-0.50</tax>
                            <gross-price>-8.45</gross-price>
                            <base-price>-7.95</base-price>
                            <tax-basis>-7.95</tax-basis>
                            <lineitem-text>$5 Expedited Shipping</lineitem-text>
                            <promotion-id>fathers_day_shipping</promotion-id>
                            <campaign-id>FATHER'S DAY $5 Shipping - 04/01/14 9:22:15 am</campaign-id>
                            <coupon-id>FATHER20</coupon-id>
                        </price-adjustment>
                        <item-id>EXPEDITED_SHIPPING</item-id>
                        <shipment-id>1234</shipment-id>
                        <tax-rate>.0635</tax-rate>
                    </shipping-lineitem>
                </shipping-lineitems>
                <shipments>
                    <shipment>
                        <shipping-method>EXPEDITED-SHIPPING</shipping-method>
                        <shipping-address>
                            <first-name>Satish</first-name>
                            <last-name>Kumar</last-name>
                            <address1>555 Christian Rd</address1>
                            <address2>Middlebury</address2>
                            <city>CT</city>
                            <postal-code>06762</postal-code>
                            <state-code>CT</state-code>
                            <country-code>US</country-code>
                            <phone>2033461234</phone>
                        </shipping-address>
                        <shipment-id></shipment-id>
                    </shipment>
                </shipments>
                <totals>
                    <merchandize-total>
                        <net-price>290.00</net-price>
                        <tax>18.42</tax>
                        <gross-price>308.42</gross-price>
                    </merchandize-total>
                    <adjusted-merchandize-total>
                        <net-price>252.00</net-price>
                        <tax>16.00</tax>
                        <gross-price>268.83</gross-price>
                    </adjusted-merchandize-total>
                    <shipping-total>
                        <net-price>12.95</net-price>
                        <tax>0.82</tax>
                        <gross-price>13.77</gross-price>
                    </shipping-total>
                    <adjusted-shipping-total>
                        <net-price>5.00</net-price>
                        <tax>0.32</tax>
                        <gross-price>5.32</gross-price>
                    </adjusted-shipping-total>
                    <order-total>
                        <net-price>257.00</net-price>
                        <tax>16.32</tax>
                        <gross-price>273.32</gross-price>
                    </order-total>
                </totals>
                <payments>
                    <payment>
                        <credit-card>
                            <card-type>VISA</card-type>
                            <card-token>AH92FU288BS</card-token>
                            <card-holder>Jon Paul</card-holder>
                            <expiration-month>1</expiration-month>
                            <expiration-year>2017</expiration-year>
                        </credit-card>
                        <amount>185.05</amount>
                        <transaction-id>XYZ123</transaction-id>
                        <processor-id>MYINFO</processor-id>
                        <transaction-type>AUTH</transaction-type>
                        <orderBusinessType>B2C</orderBusinessType>
                    </payment>
                </payments>
            </order>
        </orders>   


    XSLT USED:

    <template match="/">
          <!--HEADERS LEVEL MAPPING FOR THE ORDER IS WORKING FINE. I AM HAVING A PROBLEM WITH THE LINES MAPPING.-->
        </XxtgEcomOmsHeadersAll>
        <xxtgEcomOmsLinesAllCollection>
          <for-each select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem">
            <XxtgEcomOmsLinesAll>

              <tmxFwp>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:product-id"/>
              </tmxFwp>
              <qtyOrdered>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:quantity"/>
              </qtyOrdered>
              <lineDescription>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:product-name"/>
              </lineDescription>
              <lineStatusCode>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:status/imp1:order-status"/>
              </lineStatusCode>
              <omsLinePrice>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:net-price"/>
              </omsLinePrice>
              <omsLineTax>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:tax"/>
              </omsLineTax>
              <omsLineGrossPrice>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:gross-price"/>
              </omsLineGrossPrice>
              <omsLineBasePrice>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:base-price"/>
              </omsLineBasePrice>
              <omsLineItemText>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:lineitem-text"/>
              </omsLineItemText>
              <omsLineTaxBasis>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:tax-basis"/>
              </omsLineTaxBasis>
              <omsLineTaxRate>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:tax-rate"/>
              </omsLineTaxRate>
              <omsLineNetPriceAdj>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:price-adjustments/imp1:price-adjustment/imp1:net-price"/>
              </omsLineNetPriceAdj>
              <omsLineTaxAdj>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:price-adjustments/imp1:price-adjustment/imp1:tax"/>
              </omsLineTaxAdj>
              <omsLineGrossPriceAdj>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:price-adjustments/imp1:price-adjustment/imp1:gross-price"/>
              </omsLineGrossPriceAdj>
              <omsLineBasePriceAdj>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:price-adjustments/imp1:price-adjustment/imp1:base-price"/>
              </omsLineBasePriceAdj>
              <omsLineTaxBasisAdj>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:price-adjustments/imp1:price-adjustment/imp1:tax-basis"/>
              </omsLineTaxBasisAdj>
              <omsLinePromotionId>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:price-adjustments/imp1:price-adjustment/imp1:promotion-id"/>
              </omsLinePromotionId>
              <omsLineCompaignId>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:price-adjustments/imp1:price-adjustment/imp1:campaign-id"/>
              </omsLineCompaignId>
              <omsLineCouponId>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:price-adjustments/imp1:price-adjustment/imp1:coupon-id"/>
              </omsLineCouponId>
              <lineUnitPrice>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:base-price"/>
              </lineUnitPrice>
              <lineUnitCost>
                <value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:base-price"/>
              </lineUnitCost>
               </XxtgEcomOmsLinesAll>
          </for-each>

    </template>

Unable to do the for-each for all the nodes. That is the issue.


In out put i see first line item TW2P84400ZA repeated 3 times.
**>TW2P84400ZA<
>TW2P84400ZA<
>TW2P84400ZA<**    

Instead i need to see all the line items in the output
**>TW2P84400ZA<
>TW2P919009J<
>TW7C06900GZ<**
```

Thanks

Comment: This has the makings of a good question, but unless you show us the XSL stylesheet and sufficient actual vs expected output, this question is unanswerable and will get closed.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Since the code is too long to paste here. I have shown the precise XSLT functions that i used and the completed Input XML. All i need is to get the lines repeated in the for-each. As of now i am only able to see the same first line item repeating for the no of lines...

Comment: The first rule of asking for help is to make it easy for people to help you.  At the very _least_ show some of the actual vs expected output. Better yet, build a simpler test case demonstrating your problem that is small enough to post here.  You might actually figure out the problem yourself.  I have been on this site for 7½ years and while I've answered thousands of questions, I have asked a grand total of 21 questions, mostly because whenever I want to ask a question I usually find the answer while building a simplified version to post here.

Comment: @user3866987: Had you created a proper [mcve], Jim could have answered your question several times over by now rather than having to waste time trying to teach you how to [ask].

Comment: Apologies my way of answering the question. 1. Unable to post my complete code that was the issue. That would be great if you can interpret my question with the available information i posted, that will be helpful.

Comment: In out put i see first line item TW2P84400ZA repeated 3 times.
>TW2P84400ZA<
>TW2P84400ZA<
>TW2P84400ZA<
Instead i need to see all the line items in the output
>TW2P84400ZA<
>TW2P919009J<
>TW7C06900GZ<

Comment: Updated the Question

Comment: "*The first rule of asking for help is to make it easy for people to help you.*" Please [a] minimize your example and [b] post **valid** code (using `xsl:template` and `xsl:value-of` instead of `template` and `value-of`, and also showing the namespace declarations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, in a nutshell, is this:

When you do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem">
```

you are put in the context of `product-lineitem`. From this context, you only need to specify the relative path to the product id:

```
<xsl:value-of select="imp1:product-id"/>
```

in order to select the current line-item's `product-id`.

Instead, you do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/imp1:orders/imp1:order/imp1:product-lineitems/imp1:product-lineitem/imp1:product-id"/>
```

which selects all the `product-id` nodes in the entire document, starting from the root, and - in XSLT 1.0 -  returns the value of the first one.

Comment: This addressed my issue. Thanks for the detailed explanation, though my question was not framed as per the rules. Thanks Very Much